# Unauthenticated bind (DN with no password) disallowed

Tags: linux, ldap, openldap, oracle-enterprise-linux

I am trying to configure openldap on OEL 5.7 and I am getting this error:

## ldapadd -a -X -w -D 'cn=ldapadmin,dc=oraia,dc=com' -f initialize_ldap.ldif

ldap_bind: DSA is unwilling to perform
ldap_bind: additional info: unauthenticated bind (DN with no password) disallowed

Here is my .ldif file

```
dn: dc=oraia,dc=com
objectclass: dcObject
objectclass: organization
o: Oraia LDAP Server for Net Service Names
dc: oraia

dn: cn=ldapadmin,dc=oraia,dc=com
objectclass: organizationalRole
cn: ldapadmin
```

And here is my slapd.conf file

```
# See slapd.conf(5) for details on configuration options.
# This file should NOT be world readable.
#
include         /etc/openldap/schema/core.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/cosine.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/nis.schema

pidfile         /var/run/openldap/slapd.pid
argsfile        /var/run/openldap/slapd.args

database        bdb
suffix          "dc=oraia,dc=com"
rootdn          "cn=ldapadmin,dc=oraia,dc=com"
# Cleartext passwords, especially for the rootdn, should
# be avoided.  See slappasswd(8) and slapd.conf(5) for details.
# Use of strong authentication encouraged.
rootpw          secret
# rootpw                {crypt}ijFYNcSNctBYg
#rootpw {SSHA}rW/GYmrcz6/CZfp7vMW4Kp+wYWK9rrIk
#rootpw {CRYPT}ld1saKGO4zPbQ

directory       /var/lib/ldap

# Indices to maintain for this database
index objectClass                       eq,pres
index ou,cn,mail,surname,givenname      eq,pres,sub
index uidNumber,gidNumber,loginShell    eq,pres
index uid,memberUid                     eq,pres,sub
index nisMapName,nisMapEntry            eq,pres,sub
```

I have tried all the rootpw solutions on internet but it didn't work throw with same error as mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `ldapadd -a -x -w secret -D 'cn=ldapadmin,dc=oraia,dc=com' -f initialize_ldap.ldif`. `-X` needs an option that you don't want, and you need to provide the password to `-w`. Note that `secret` comes from your slapd.conf; if you changed it while posting use the real one.

Comment: Sorry! it does'nt work and display the following menu like stuff

Comment: When I try the command you told it gives me the help menu, like when some arguments are wrong.

Comment: In your suggested edit, the path name of your ldapadd is /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/bin/ldapadd - which is not the OS ldapadd, but the one provided with the oracle database. That version is quite old, and in the meantime, the ldap tools have been reworked considerably, with command line option names changed. Make sure you have the openldap-clients package installed, and give the complete path `/usr/bin/ldapadd` when calling the command.

Comment: Or, if you want to use the (old) oracle command, omitting `-a` and `-x` should work.

Comment: Sorry, can't help you there because i'm not familiar with the ldap schema you need for the Oracle LDAP naming adapter.